# I want to send a message to a specific channel when my discord.py bot enables

Tags: discord.py

How to send a message to a specific channel when my discord.py bot enables
i am using the new discord.py in which (ctx) is a thing

Answer (score 0):

After you get the channel ID, you can use

```
channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, id = channelID) #or name if you want by name
await channel.send("This is a test message!")
```

Comment: You could also use `bot.get_channel(12345)` to get it from cache. without getting a guild object